# Harmonic motion of droplet of a non-viscous fluid

Tags: fluid-dynamics, harmonic-oscillator, dimensional-analysis

We are given that there is drop of density $d_1$ and radius $r_1$ with a surface tension $T$.Next we are told that the drop is made into an ellipsoidal shape.

[image]

How do we find the time period of S.H.M of the drop?

My attempt:-

I found excess pressure acting on the drop in the deformed shape and computed the integral

$\vec{P}.\vec{dA}$ to find the the excess force on the droplet.

This is turning out to be very messy and does not give an accurate answer.

So, is there an short and sweet way to do this problem?
Please help me out and tell me if my method is wrong or if there is a better way to do it.

Note this is the original problem and it is a question based on dimensional analysis

However I wanted to find the right way how to do it,and also find the numerical constant it is proportional to.

[image]

Comment: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/265161468_Oscillation_of_a_Liquid_Drop_in_a_Zero-Gravity_Environment_-_A_Benchmark_Problem_for_Two-Phase_Flow_Computations

Answer (score 0):

A simple dimensional analysis yields the answer. We begin with the question: What can the time period of the oscillation, $T$, depend on? It will depend on surface tension $\sigma$ of the drop, its size $R$, and density $d$. Now, [dimensional homogeneity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneity_(physics)#:%7E:text=As%20said%20in%20the%20introduction,errors%20in%20formula%20or%20calculations.) of any equation describing physical phenomena, together with [Buckingham Pi theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buckingham_%CF%80_theorem), implies that any physical phenomenon must be described in terms of dimensionless quantities alone. Only one dimensionless quantity can be formed with $T,\sigma,R,d,$ viz. $T\sqrt{\sigma/dR^3}$. Therefore we must have, $T\sqrt{\sigma/dR^3}=C$, where $C$ is a constant. Thus, since surface tension is the same for both drops, we have:
$$
\frac{T_1}{T_2}=\sqrt{\frac{d_1R_1^3}{d_2R_2^3}}
$$